# Trying an intent and crash the app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an intent that connect a button with a class (definition of intent). The problem is that, when I press this button, everything crash. I think that the problem is in the intent class. Can you see what's wrong? I'm trying to open an alert dialog when button bet is pressed. I have already create it:

Chips class, the class aI want to use after the button is pressed:

```
public class Chips extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
}


private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
public void scommessa () {

    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText txtInput = new EditText (this);
    final String stringInput = txtInput.getText().toString();
    dialog.setTitle("Welcome to poker");
    dialog.setMessage("Player 2, place your bet!");
    dialog.setView(txtInput);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Bet", new Dialog.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int bet1 = 100;
            int intInput = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);
            int newPlayer1Bet = bet1 - intInput;
            String total1 = "" + newPlayer1Bet;

        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Pass", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 2 won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialogPoker = dialog.create();
    dialogPoker.show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.Cover1:
            scommessa();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is the class where I defined the button and then try to call the class Chips:

```
    final Button Cover1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cover1);
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A);
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C);
final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.D);
final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E);
final Button Bet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Cover1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.equals(Cover1)){
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
                        button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
                        button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
                        button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
                        button5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View x){
                if(x.equals(Bet)){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                Chips chip = new Chips();
                chip.scommessa();
                }
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
                                    //startActivity(intent1);
                    Chips chip = new Chips();
                chip.scommessa();
                }
                });
```

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pokeroriginal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pokeroriginal.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GameActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pokeroriginal.GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name= "com.example.pokeroriginal.Chips"
        android:label= "@string/Bet" 
        android:screenOrientation= "landscape" 
        android:theme= "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Also the activity_game.xml where all the buttons are defined:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/green_table_cloth"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".GameActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cover1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cover"
        android:onClick="onClickChips" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/A"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/C"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/D"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/E"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick(View x)"
        android:text="@string/Bet" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Bet" />

</ImageSwitcher>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cover2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cover" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/A2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/C2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/D2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/E2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!--    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/Image" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView> '
     -->
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Bet" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your error log and manifest too ?

Comment: Yeah sure, look at the update in 30 seconds

Comment: The error is basically the crash of the entire app when I click the button Bet

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine what the error is without seeing the logcat - you should really include it in the future.

Looking at your code, I notice this in the button1 OnClickListener:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
startActivity(intent1);
Chips chip = new Chips();
chip.scommessa();
```

To start another activity, **all** you need to do is this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

I believe that trying to instantiate the Activity using it's constructor is causing problems. When you do this, the Activity's Views have not been setup properly, and when you try to show a dialog, you will encounter errors.
Try removing these lines:

```
Chips chip = new Chips();
chip.scommessa();
```

Your OnClickListener should look like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View x) {
        if (x.equals(Bet)) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting NullPointerException here.

```
 if(x.equals(Bet))
```

and your xml onClick() implemented wrongly.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick(View x)"
    android:text="@string/Bet" />
```

java code should be like this,

```
    final Button Cover1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cover1);
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A);
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C);
final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.D);
final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E);
final Button Bet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

Cover1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
       button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
       button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
       button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
       button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
       button5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
      }
    });

  Bet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Chips chip = new Chips();
        chip.scommessa();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
  });
```

Or if you're xml implementation should be like this.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="NavigateToChips"
    android:text="@string/Bet" />
```

and you should implement onClick() method in activity like this,

```
public void NavigateToChips(View v) {
    Chips chip = new Chips();
    chip.scommessa();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Chips.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout file, I see an attribute `android:onClick="onClickChips"` for the component having id as `android:id="@+id/Cover1"`. Hence the java code would typically look for the method with name `onClickChips()`, whereas you've used an `setOnClickListener()` for `Cover1` button.

**Solution:**
Either remove the attribute (`android:onClick="onClickChips"`) from your XML or remove the `setOnClickListener()` for that button. Keep only one.